How does Java handle input characters in this program? What buffer looks like?
How does this Java program work and what is its output?
I'm working on a Java program that loops until the letter S is entered. Here is the code:
// Loops until the letter S is entered
class ForTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws java.io.IOException {

        int i;
        char x;
        System.out.println("Enter 'S' to stop.");

        for(i = 0; (x = (char) System.in.read()) != 'S'; i++) {
            System.out.println("Iteration " + i + ", read character: " + x);
        }
    }
}

My Question
Why does the program display extra iterations even if I enter only one character (L in this case)?
For a single character input like "h", I expect the output to be:
Iteration 0, read character: h
But instead, I get:
Iteration 0, read character: h

Iteration 1, read character:

Iteration 2, read character: 

Thanks in advance! I'm new to Java and trying to understand how things work in this case.
I tried printing characters in the loop, but the 2 last characters seem to be whitespace

This is a confusing way to write a while loop.

Not all characters have visible glyphs.  When you press Enter on most systems, you send a control character, '\u000a' (the “Line Feed” character), to the program.  On Windows, pressing Enter will send two characters:  "\u000d\u000a" (the “Carriage Return” character followed by the “Line Feed” character).  This is not a behavior specific to Java;  all programs will act this way.

"Carriage Return" character + "Line Feed" character is the answer to my question
Thanks a lot VGR

Terminal Mode
By default, the java terminal is in so-called ‘cooked‘ mode. Cooked mode does a whole bunch of things. One of them, is that no input is actually sent to your System.in whatsoever until the user presses enter.
In other words, if you write this very simplistic java application:
void main(String[] args) {
  while (true) {
    int c = System.in.read();
    if (c == -1) break;
    System.out.println("CharCode: " + c + " which is character '" + ((char) c) + "'");
  }
}

and you ran it and typed, with plenty of time in between keystrokes, 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', (enter key), then nothing would be printed by your java app until you hit enter and then in one go all 6 to 7 keystrokes arrive in one fell swoop. The h, the e, two ls, an o, and 'a new line' which is code 10 (you can write that as 10, '\n', or 0x0A - they all mean '10' and there is therefore absolutely no difference whatsoever between those 3 forms - whichever one makes your code most readable, and no doubt, that'd be '\n') on most OSes, but tends to be 2 characters (namely, 13 followed by 10, more readably, \r followed by \n, or 0x0D 0x0A - no difference, you see it stated in all these forms in various sites and tutorials) specifically on Microsoft Windows.
That's presumably what happened in your example: you pressed h, and then you hit enter and that is itself also a character. You're on windows, so it's 2 characters in fact, hence, 3 iterations total. One for the 'h', one for the '\r' and one for the '\n'.
I want to read one char at a time
Oof. Very difficult. (1) You need to first tell the OS to go to uncooked mode which is OS dependent and java has no baked in way to do this, you need to send a magic sequence appropriate for your OS, and (2) uncooked mode has a lot of downsides. For example, your output looks like:
Enter your name: Joe
                    Hi Joe!

i.e. 'println' does not necessarily move the cursor back anymore, and exactly how weird uncooked mode gets again depends on OS.
If you want uncooked, you need a library to make it easy, and they do exist. Lanterna for example. But, really, if you want more advanced 'UI' than simply 'enter stuff and hit enter' you should probably not be having a text based interface in the first place, and make that a graphical one (via swing or javafx or by doing what everybody's been doing for the past decade, and making a web interface for it).
No I'm fine with reading whole lines in one go; just wondering what those 3 iterations are about.
Grand! Then to read text input, you probably want this instead:
void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner s = new Scanner(system.in);
  s.useDelimiter("\\R");

  System.out.println("Hi there! What is your full name?");
  String fullName = s.next();
  System.out.println("Good to meet you, " + fullName + "!");

  System.out.println("How old are you?");
  int age = s.nextInt();
}

Note, there's a nextLine method. Do not use it. It does what its spec says it does which is not what you'd expect. next() already reads a whole line (because we fixed the delimiter).
NB: To future readers - this answer will soonish (matter of a few years) be obsolete, and the correct answer instead becomes 'use the static methods in java.io.IO'. As that is still in preview, it is not (yet) an appropriate answer to this question.
NB: The terminal is in cooked mode by default. if you hook anything else up to System.in, that won't be. For example if you ran java yourapp.Application <someFile then System.in() wouldn't buffer line by line; you'd just get characters one at a time as one would expect. The buffering stuff isn't done by java at all; java just treats System.in as a simple pipe and does not buffer it unless you ask it to by wrapping it in BufferedInputStream. It's the OS/terminal that is doing it. You can ask it to stop doing this - but it stops doing many more things - that's called 'asking for uncooked mode'. You.. don't want that, it's not for beginners.

13=0x0D is Carriage Return in ASCII denoted \r in Java (and C, and other derivatives); 10=0x0A is Line Feed OR Newline (with the latter popularized by Unix and C) denoted \n. The Windows/MSDOS convention, also used in many Internet standards such as SMTP/822 FTP HTTP, is CR LF = 0x0D 0x0A .

@dave_thompson_085 I got my CRs and LFs all twisted around. Gracias for noticing, I shall fix this answer.

Here is the solution shown below

To avoid reading these unwanted newline characters, you can implement a logic to skip over them. One way to achieve this is to use a BufferedReader which allows you to read entire lines

Here is the code snippets shown below
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int i = 0;
        char x;

        System.out.println("Enter 'S' to stop.");
        
        while (true) {
            x = (char) reader.read(); // Read the character
            if (x == 'S') break; // Exit if 'S' is entered
            if (x == '\n' || x == '\r') continue; // Skip newline characters
            
            System.out.println("Iteration " + i + ", read character: " + x);
            i++;
        }
}

